# Determining how to make a matrix have less pivots than columns (Example)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I'm studying the following example and I can't figure out why the answer is what it is:

"Find the value of $a$ that will give less that 3 pivots".
$$A = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & a & 0 \\
    1 & 2 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I got lucky and put the matrix with $a=3$ in Wolfram Alpha and saw that 3 is the only value that meets that condition, but I have no idea why. Could someone explain why that is and what I should be thinking in order to come to that conclusion?

Comment: You want the determinant to be zero.

Comment: @DavidPeterson Oof, total brain fart on my end, but thank you nonetheless! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take a direct approach here by row reducing. 
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & a & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right]
\xrightarrow{R_2-\frac{1}{2}\cdot R_1\to R_2}\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & a & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{2} \, a + 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_2\leftrightarrow R_3}\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & a & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{2} \, a + 2 & 1
\end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_3-\left(\frac{1}{2}\,a-2\right)\cdot R_2\to R_3}\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & a & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & a - 3
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
These reductions show that our matrix $A$ is row equivalent to 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & a & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & a - 3
\end{array}\right]
$$
What is the rank of this new matrix?